# Why is this JavaScript not working on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone

I have this JavaScript code that works on desktop devices. The code redirects the old page the user was on when they open a link. Eg. The user is on the website (tab 1) they click the link, the link opens (Tab 2) and (tab 1) redirects to another page.

```
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(".feed-item a");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onclick = function() {
        location.href="/exit-page/";
    }
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work on mobile devices as the link doesn't open in a new window it just redirects straight away and doesn't actually open the link

Comment: Usually, new tabs are opened in the background and you stay on the same page. At least in the case of Chrome for Android. Sometimes it depends on your browser settings.

Comment: May be onclick is different from touchstart which is another event

Comment: I have tried touchstart but it's still not working on IOS

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, location.href is a read-only property so your url cannot open in mobile devices. Folowing code try

```
window.location='url';
```

Comment: Hi, it's still not working I'm testing it on a IPhone using IOS if that helps